# NSObject track properties changed

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

I need to know a list of properties changed on an NSObject without creating custom setters for every property (lots of different classes and properties). Is there something like a super setter that I can overwrite?

It would also be nice if I could reset it.

Comment: Try KVO, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: That would mean I have to add an observer for _every_ property on every object, with the possibility of 500+ objects with each 10+ properties.

Comment: You could use method swizzeling to first run your own code and then just call original implementation of the setter/getter. Super scary so be sure that what you are doing is super correct x 3.

Comment: Uhm, let's use that as a last resort. Not really comfortable with that hackery.

Comment: If you want you can add 500 properties or you can use objc runtime, get all properties dynamically from classes and add observers dynamically. Currently I do not see what you are going to achieve with this that. If you want to reset some properties in some cases, you will still need to write custom handling logic.